# Dynamic action with filter based on Role is not visible on record page

Tags: lightning-experience, action, dynamic-actions

I am stuck in one thing.
I have added one dynamic action on record page with filter based on Role.
When logging in with end user with this Role, I am still not able to see this action on my record page.
We are not giving any access to profile as we are dealing in Permission sets here.
OWD for Opportunity: Public read/Write,
Also given Read/Create/Edit access for Opportunity in Permission set.

Note: I am able to see the action with Admin profile(For other profile I have added my permission set for user.)

Kindly help.

Steps followed by me to Configure the dynamic action:  I edited the lightning record page --> selected highlight panel -> Selected my action --> Added filter as USer->Role->Name equals "Leasing Admin".

When I am trying to login by real time user whose profile is not system admin but role is "Leasing Admin" , This action is not visible.

Comment: be helpful if you used [edit] and you showed how you configured the dynamic action

Comment: I had this same issue - It was a "Dynamic Related List - Single" on a Lightning page.  The filter was set to show for specific roles, under the "Advanced" settings on the "Add Filter".

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether system permission **View Roles and Role Hierarchy** has been checked to true for the profile for which you are trying to see dynamic action button if you have configured it role specific.